# Is it possible to implement both CDNBye and Agora SDK in a Flutter mobile application

Tags: android, flutter, agora

I'm building a flutter mobile application that will focus on p2p live video streaming as well as cost effective for the CDN since it can be really expensive to run a CDN. Is it possible to achieve such combinations in a mobile app? where Agora SDK focusing on RTC and CDN focusing on peer-to-peer content delivery.

Comment: Have you tried? is cdnbye p2p working ?